# Why is there no Facebook share button on thank-you pages?

Tags: civicontribute, social-media, facebook

When you create contribtuion pages in CiviCRM you can choose to "Allow sharing through social media"

The following image appears at the bottom of your thank-you page when the contribution has been processed.[image]
There is a Facebook like, but no Facebook share.  Is there a technical reason for that or has no-one seen a need for it before?

Comment: I have a request for this too.  Has any one added the share link?